# Coalescing rows in pyspark with string operation

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am looking to coalesce duplicate rows of a pyspark dataframe from this:

[image]

to  this:

[image]

I need to have a period after each sentence of the coalesced rows. I tried *coalesce()* and *collect_set()* but can't perform the string operation within the collected window/group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anaother way:

```
df= (df2.groupby('ID','fname','lname','Score').agg(collect_list('Activity').alias('Activity'))#Create an array of Activity 
        .withColumn('Activity', concat(array_join('Activity','.'),lit('.')))#join array and then concatenate dot
     
    ).show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: Gave you an upvote, please upvote for the answer if it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `concat_ws` with the `collect_list`.
Although, this won't guarantee the order of sentences as Spark table is unordered. If you care the order, you need some sequential column to order upon.

```py
(df.groupBy('ID')
 .agg(*[F.col(x).alias(x) for x in ['fname', 'lname', 'Score']],
      F.concat_ws(' ', F.collect_list(F.col('Activity'))).alias('Activity'))
)
```